# JasperReport : apply rounding on variable

Tags: jasper-reports, bigdecimal

I have a group band in my report. In my group footer band I display a variable that represents the sum of all fieldvalues in detail band.
I want to apply BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN to it.
I did :

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{montantHt1}.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN)]]></textFieldExpression>
```

But in my report I still  get values like 1487.85 whereas I should get 1488.00

Comment: If you SetScale to 2, you should get what you get, and not `x.00`. You can get what you want if you first set scale to 0 (using ROUND_HALF_DOWN) and then to 2.

Comment: IOW: `$V{montantHt1}.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN).SetScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UNNECESSARY)`